# Is there something like a state of memory, present in emulator games, in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, memory, emulation, state

I would like to create a function in PHP that will change a database to defaults values.
This will save defaults values:

```
<?php
  mysql_save_state(database, file);
?>
```

After that, my code would be something like that:

```
<?php
  // when i reload, set my database to default
  mysql_load_state(database, file);
  // my code
  // changes in database
?>
```

It will be used only to development, by me.

Translated:

> Eu gostaria de criar uma função em PHP que faça o meu banco de dados
>   voltar para o padrão. Assim, toda vez que eu recarregar o script, ele
>   estará de uma maneira que previamente escolhi.

Comment: This is an English only site. Please translate everything.

Comment: You want to return your database to a previous state.. you can create an sql and return the database using the sql file... but that is not how databases work (states). Why you want that?

Comment: everything is translated.
im writing a card game, and the hand of a person is generate by random.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to keep the application state in a specific array / object, then serialize() that array and write it to storage. You can then restore the current state by querying the database and calling unserialize() on the result again. You can extend an object with `__wakeup` and `__sleep` methods to run code on serialization and deserialization as well.

If the user can only have one active game at a time, using the standard `Session` module through `$_SESSION` should suffice, as it allows you to keep state between different page views.

Serializing the complete state of the application is (usually) not a good idea for web applications, as each request will be different. Keep the state you want to serialize in an object by itself and serialize that.

Comment: thanks. my database has few data. everytime that i run the script, all tables is cleaned and, after, reconstructed. if i could create a state, i didnt have to wait the reconstructed.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm telling you. Why are you cleaning the tables on each run? That seems rather counter-productive.

Comment: because i wrote one code to take a card from the deck thats is randomically. like an emulator of consoles, it will help me, i would like to know if it exists.

Comment: I think you need to approach this problem differently; there is nothing stopping you from having state stored in the database - that's what sessions are designed to do. People writing emulators are not storing the complete state of the emulator when they're writing state to disk, but the state of the hardware being emulated (memory and cpu). By keeping the relevant state in an array by itself and serializing/deserializing that, you're practically implementing the same thing (and that $_SESSION does transparently for you).